# Java and whitespace-as-syntax (ala Python)?

Tags: java, python, syntax, whitespace

There is a part of java syntax that bugs the crap out of me: that's curly braces and semicolons. Is there some sort of translator that exists that will allow me to use all of the Java syntax except for this? I want to do something like this:

```
public class Hello:
    public static void main(String[] args):
        System.out.println("I like turtles.")

public class Another:
    public static void somethingelse():
        System.out.println("And boobs")
```

It's Python's whitespace as syntax model, I've grown to love it. I believe it's cleaner, and easier on the eyes. If it doesn't exist, I'm actually considering heavily investing time into writing a parser that would do this for me.  (Ideally it will open it up, format it with whitespace, and when saved, save as just java syntax with braces and all)

Would this cause problems elsewhere in the language? What kind of hiccups can I expect to run into?  I want to use all of the rest of the Java syntax exactly how it is otherwise, just want to modify this small niggle.

I can *already* write and read code just fine in Eclipse.  And yes, I already know how to use code formatting tools and all the auto-complete options available to me, this is merely a preference in coding style so please don't answer with "You should learn to get used to it" or "You should use an IDE that does braces FOR you"...no.  I don't want that.

Comment: There's a project on google code that let's you do this with C. I can't find a link to it right now but it might be worth looking for. If you end up having to implement this yourself, then it might provide a good starting point.

Comment: I totally get where you're coming from, but in all honesty you should just get used to it. Do you think it's really worth the trouble of writing your own parser, just so you can get rid of curly braces and semicolons?

Comment: I think it's good to have a quest. You'll have to watch out for `for` loops and quoted strings, also foreaches and `switch`es as they can all use the characters you need to translate. Array initialisers and static blocks too... eeep, you've got your work cut out for you.

Comment: Yes, I couldn't agree more.  If you end up doing this, please post it here.  Other things to consider: whether you want to also change standards like (True vs true) (z = x if c else y vs z=c?x:y), and what to do with Java's multi-line lambdas.  Something like list comprehensions in Java would also be great.

Answer (score 2):

Can you switch to Jython? Python's syntax, Java's runtime environment.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I'm mainly working on Android at the moment, Jython doesn't compile anything compatible.  I'm not really looking for the entire Python syntax either though; Just the indentation-based syntax.  I already use Jython for some of my own personal projects.  There was a "Jythonroid" project, but it was superceded by SL4A (previously ASE) but SL4A doesn't have access to SurfaceFlinger or any of the GUI/layout subsystems.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider instead investing time in learning to use eclipse and the code formatter.

Python's model is great in that it (more or less) forces all developers into the same code style format. Modern software firms have code-style guidelines and use IDEs with formatters to ease enforcement of the coding style. Even if your coworkers have (subjectively)atrocious styles(to you), you can quickly reformat that code into something you find readable.

Comment: I can already write code fine and read code fine with the braces and semicolons, it's merely a preference.  I already use Eclipse and can handle the code formatter with ease.  It's not about typing less or anything like that.  Optimally it would be a tool for my use that would convert both ways.  It would take a source file and format it in the way I prefer, and then upon saving, would export as regular java, braces and all; It wouldn't affect any of the code at all. (at least that's how I envision it.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) or [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), which drops most of curly braces and semicolons (as far as dots and parenthesis). Their syntax is much more readable, and you still all the power of JVM.

Though, if you need exactly translator (to save it as a plain Java code), you can easily write such translator by yourself. Read input file line by line, counting indents, and each time it changes, delete colon at the end of the string (if needed) and insert curly brace: opening brace for bigger indent and closing for smaller. (It doesn't take into account several possible cases, but most of them is considered as bad style.)

Comment: I noticed your comment  about Android, please, ignore first paragraph. EDIT: [or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476111/scala-programming-for-android)